# Disable Mat-Select Option inside mat-table once it has been selected in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

Just need some home on how to disable Mat-Select Option once it has been selected from other row inside a mat-table.
[image]

```
       <ng-container matColumnDef="billingRegisterId" >
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="direction: ltr">
                    <h6><b>Billing Reference and Description</b></h6>
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element " [formGroup]="element">
                    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="none" style="text-align: left">
                      <mat-select formControlName="billingRegisterId" required >
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let billingRegisterOutstandingBalance of billingRegisterOutstandingBalances  | sort:'sequenceNo'" [value]="billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.id">
                          {{ billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.sequenceNo +' | '+ billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.description1}}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Can you add more context?, selected by what?, you want to disable an option or the select?.

Comment: Hi cabesuon, really appreciate your time taking my question, I'd just like to disable the option not the select, if user has already selected the option value, that selected item should no be available or disabled in other rows, the purpose is to avoid duplication of value inside mat-table

Comment: Just added an image for easy reference

Comment: It still needs more info. Could you build a simplified version on [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dkmeaooabxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)? It depends on how you've set up things on typescript code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of values to choose from `billingRegisterOutstandingBalances`, and if one of the values is already selected you want to disable it from others `select`.

One simple way it occurs to me, is to add a boolean attribute (`selected`) to the objects of the list (or to have a secondary boolean list and use the index), and then just add a simple condition for `option` `disabled` property. Something like this,

```
<mat-option 
*ngFor="let billingRegisterOutstandingBalance of billingRegisterOutstandingBalances  | sort:'sequenceNo'"
[value]="billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.id"
[disabled]="billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.selected">
  {{ billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.sequenceNo +' | '+ billingRegisterOutstandingBalance.description1}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: You're right cabesuon, I'll try your suggestion.. thanks.. thanks

Comment: Glad it helps you! .. If it solves your problem please mark it as the answer for future reference